# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not IDbDataParameter[] objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method for inserting data into the database:
**Before Update**

```
public DataSet Get(WorkEntry t, string callingPage, string operation)
{ 
    // Start the Insert Update Method
    IDbDataParameter[] param = null;

    DataSet returnValue = null;

    try
    {
        param = CreateParams(t, callingPage, operation);

        param[0].Value = t.AutoID;
        param[1].Value = t.OperatorName;
        param[2].Value = t.Date;
        param[3].Value = t.StartDate;
        param[4].Value = t.EndDate;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spWorkEntry";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        da_G = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        cmdB_G = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_G);
        da_G.Fill(returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        param = null;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}// End the Insert Update Method
```

### -----------------------------------

**After Update**

```
 // Get-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public DataSet Get(WorkEntry t, string callingPage, string operation)
        { // Start the Insert Update Method
            SqlParameter[] param = null;
            DataSet returnValue = null;
            try
            {
                param = (SqlParameter[])CreateParams(t, callingPage, operation);

                param[0].Value = t.AutoID;
                param[1].Value = "sdf";
                param[2].Value = t.Date;
                param[3].Value = t.StartDate;
                param[4].Value = t.EndDate;


                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "spWorkEntry";
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                da_G = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                cmdB_G = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_G);
                da_G.Fill(returnValue);

                return returnValue;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                param = null;
                command.Parameters.Clear();

            }
        }// End the Insert Update Method
        // Get End -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Error is happening on this line:

```
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Param is the array of `IDbDataParameter[]` & values in the arrays are as follows:

```
param[0].Value = 123;
param[1].Value = "asdf";
param[2].Value = "sdfs";
param[3].Value = "sdfsdf";
param[4].Value = "sdfsdf";
```

Then error also happens as param should be non nullable.

Answer (score 0):

There are no overloads of `Add()` that take an array as a parameter. The only reason this compiles is because there is an overload that takes an `object`. A quick [search of MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136441(v=vs.110).aspx) would reveal an `AddRange` method that will accept an array of `SqlParameter`. So you should make your array type `SqlParameter[]` instead of `IDBDataParameter[]`, or cast it if there is other code using it and relying on that interface.

Comment: changed the code as you told me then also same error coming please check the updated question

Comment: @HardikParmar, `AddRange()`, not `Add()`. This is a common pattern in .Net when a Type can accept an array - look for `AddRange` method.